# Split large JSON file by using jq and awk

Tags: json, powershell, awk, jq

I have a large file called

```
Metadata_01.json
```

It consistst of blocks that following this structure:

```
[
 {
  "Participant_id": "P04_00001",
  "no_of_people": "Multiple",
  "apparent_gender": "F",
  "geographic_location": "AUS",
  "ethnicity": "Caucasian",
  "capture_device_used": "iOS 14",
  "camera_orientation": "Portrait",
  "camera_position": "Side View",
  "indoor_outdoor_env": "Indoors",
  "lighting_condition": "Bright",
  "Occluded": 1,
  "category": "Two Person",
  "camera_movement": "Still",
  "action": "No action",
  "indoor_outdoor_in_moving_car_or_train": "Indoor",
  "daytime_nighttime": "Nighttime"
 },
 {
  "Participant_id": "P04_00002",
  "no_of_people": "Single",
  "apparent_gender": "M",
  "geographic_location": "AUS",
  "ethnicity": "Caucasian",
  "capture_device_used": "iOS 14",
  "camera_orientation": "Portrait",
  "camera_position": "Frontal View",
  "indoor_outdoor_env": "Outdoors",
  "lighting_condition": "Bright",
  "Occluded": "None",
  "category": "Animals",
  "camera_movement": "Still",
  "action": "Small action",
  "indoor_outdoor_in_moving_car_or_train": "Outdoor",
  "daytime_nighttime": "Daytime"
 },
```

And so on... thousands of them.

I am using the following command:

```
jq -cr '.[]' Metadata_01.json | awk '{print > (NR ".json")}'
```

And it's kinda doing the expected work.

[From large file that is structured like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoeZg.jpg)

[I am getting tons of files that named like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQvqB.jpg)

[And structure like this (in one line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ovh2.png)

Instead of those results I need each json file to be named after the "Participant_id" (e.g. P04_00002.json)
And I want to preserve the json structure to look like that for each file

```
{
  "Participant_id": "P04_00002",
  "no_of_people": "Single",
  "apparent_gender": "M",
  "geographic_location": "AUS",
  "ethnicity": "Caucasian",
  "capture_device_used": "iOS 14",
  "camera_orientation": "Portrait",
  "camera_position": "Frontal View",
  "indoor_outdoor_env": "Outdoors",
  "lighting_condition": "Bright",
  "Occluded": "None",
  "category": "Animals",
  "camera_movement": "Still",
  "action": "Small action",
  "indoor_outdoor_in_moving_car_or_train": "Outdoor",
  "daytime_nighttime": "Daytime"
 }
```

What adjustments should I make to the command above to achieve this?
Or maybe there's an easier way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would recommend using PowerShell since working with objects tends to be easier overall. Fortunately, PowerShell has a `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet you can use to convert the returned text into a PS object letting you reference the properties via dot notation (`.Participant_id`). Then, you'd just have to convert each iteration back to JSON format and export it. Here I use `New-Item` to create the file with the output but piping to `Out-File` would work as well.

```bash
$json = Get-Content -Path '.\Metadata_01.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json 
foreach ($json_object in $json)
{
    New-Item -Path ".\Desktop\" -Name "$($json_object.Participant_id).json" -Value (ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $json_object) -ItemType 'File' -Force
}
```

The issue I can see you *probably* running into is not enough memory, due to the size of that file since you'll be saving to a variable first in this example. There are ways around it but this is for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 2):

> What adjustments should I make ...?

I'd go with:

```
jq -cr '.[] | (.Participant_id, .)' Metadata_01.json | awk '
  NR%2==1 {fn="id." $0 ".json"; next} {print >> fn; close(fn); }
'
```

and then run something like `jq . "$FILE" | sponge "$FILE"` to pretty-print each file.

Alternatively, if you can navigate your way around any issues that might arise when escaping quotation marks, you could get awk to call jq:

```
jq -cr '.[] | (.Participant_id, .)' Metadata_01.json | awk -v q=$'\'' '
  NR%2==1 {fn = "id." $0 ".json"; next}
  {  system( ("jq . <<< " q $0 q " >> \"" fn "\"") );
     close(fn);
  }
'
```

#### "Big Data"

Of course if the input file is too large or too slow for `jq empty`, then you will want to consider alternatives, e.g. jq's `--stream` option, `jstream`, or my own [jm](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jm). For example if you want the JSON to be pretty-printed in each file:

```
while read -r json
do
   fn=$(jq -r .Participant_id <<< "$json")
   <<< "$json" jq . > "id.$fn.json"
done < <(jm Metadata_01.json)
```

Comment: @EdMorton - Tx.